# Sybase SQL Anywhere automated email triggers

Tags: sqlanywhere

I have been trying to create a trigger in Sybase SQL which generates an automated email when a row is inserted into the table.
Here is the explanation:
I have a table by the name inventory, which contains a column name packing_number. When i insert a new row in this table, I want an automated email to be generated and sent to multiple recipients which displays me the packing_number and other columns exported into a .csv file.

I know how to export the data into a file, but i am still stuck as to how can i incorporate the automated email part into the trigger.

Please help. 
Thanks in advance.
And i apologize for any missing information.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Anywhere has built-in functions for sending email. Check out the [xp_startsmtp](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbreference/xp-startsmtp-system-procedure.html%2ad5e90190) and [xp_sendmail](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbreference/xp-sendmail-system-procedure.html) functions. Note that these links are to the v16 docs, but they exist in previous versions as well.

Comment: I really thank you for your input to this. I am looking forward to understand the concept behind them. I have been trying to read this and was wondering where i would get the smtp server name for the process.